# Chrome image caching (without reloading the page)

Tags: google-chrome, cache-control, etag

I have an angular application which loads html documents from a backend server these documents also include images.

On these files i have an `eTag` header and `cache-control: no-cache`. When i do an ajax request i see that the HTML documents get checked using the `eTag` but the images are not checked they are just retrieved from the cache.

When i request the images again after a while (+- 5 minutes) then chrome does check the images with the server by `eTag`.

I tried changing to `cache-control: no-store` and this appears to be working for the images now they are retrieved from the server on every request.
But when `no-store` is used then the browser wont use the `eTag` and always downloads the files (as it should).

I know that i could add a time variable to the url (`image.png?12345`) and that works aswell, but again then the `eTag` is not used and the images are downloaded every request.

Am i doing something wrong or is chrome adding some extra caching logic for images?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try modifying urls so that they would look like (image.png?eTag=your_tag). That would make an image reload as soon as eTag changes.

Comment: This is not the ideal solution, but it works :)
now i have to request the eTag of the image build the url and then request the image.